# Is it allowed to buy a Probe Bahncard 50 repeatedly?

Tags: trains, tickets, legal, germany, deutsche-bahn

I bought a Probe BahnCard 50. It is now expired (I cancelled the subscription) and the trial period of 3 months is over. Can I buy a Probe BahnCard subscription again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deutsche Bahn confirm [here](https://community.bahn.de/questions/2000238-probebahncard-mehrmals-hintereinander-bestellen) (and in other answers on their community site) that it is permitted:

> Man kann die Probebahncard bestellen so oft man möchte. Aber auch eine Probebahncard ist ein Abo und muss spätestens 6 Wochen vor Gültigkeitsende gekündigt werden.

("One can order the Probe Bahncard as often as one likes. But even a Probe Bahncard is a subscription and must be cancelled at the latest six weeks before the end of its validity.")

Comment: You can cancel the subscription right on buying it. They have a form for that at ticket counters.